# Add total documents matched to a user ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get the total orders matched to an individual user.

Here is my orders schema:

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
    lineItems: [{
        product: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Product"
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number
        }
    }],
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    }]
});
```

Here is my mongoose query:

```
getOrderTotal: function (req, res) {
    const userID = req.params.userid;
    Order
      .aggregate([
        { $match: { 'user': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID) } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            localField: "lineItems.product",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "product"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$product",
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$lineItems"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID),
            count: { $sum: 1 }

          }
        }
      ])
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
```

Each user I test, the count field always returns a value of 72.  There are not even a total of 72 orders in the db.  When I change the 1 value to a different number, it returns some multiple of 72 i.e. 2 returns 144, 0.5 returns 36.

Comment: $unwind create this problem. Please provide data for solve query.

Comment: How does $unwind create the problem?

Comment: When you find product using lookup stag they give some result and when you unwind this they become lots of result an again unwind give to much doc.  Now you have to use group twice.

Comment: I am using $unwind so that I can also get information about the products to calculate things like total revenue generated by one user.  Is there a way to do this while also while also getting a total of all of the orders for one user?

Comment: You need to group or match to get required result in for wind data again.

Comment: Do you have a solution?